# Saved Parquet data into S3, creating table in athena brings null values for int unsigned,

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I created a data catalog in glue based on an RDS database. Then i created a job to convert a single table into s3 as a parquet format.

Now i go to Athena and hit create table from that location in s3.
The problem is my original RDS table has columns with data types as int unsigned. Those columns have null values when i create the table and query it from athena.
I did the same thing but instead of parquet format i used JSON and all works fine
Why does parquet brings me null values, is there something i can do?

Comment: OP did you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes , found a solution

Comment: Can you please share?

Comment: Hi Golden, it was a long time ago, but, what we did, we changed the data types of the original tables from unsigned to int(11), original tables are MySQL.